# Jiffy lube put too much oil in my car

Tags: oil

I had an oil change at jiffy lube at 10,000 miles. I have just gone to another jiffy lube and was told that the oil is one inch too high. I have not added any oil. I have driven in normal conditions for approximately 7,500 miles. Will this damage my car in any way? Do I need to check anything out in my car to confirm that it is fine? I read that my catalytic converter could be at risk from this. Is this something that I need to worry about?

Thank you!

My car is a 2014 Kia Optima

Comment: You haven't said what model car you have, but it is worth mentioning, that on some older models with carburettors, the fuel pumps can sometimes get a fault that allows fuel to pass into the engine oil.  If your engine oil level seems to be increasing over time, then this needs investigating.

Comment: Was the car hot at the second Jiffy Lube?

Comment: This is probably a closer fit than the "one gallon" question: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/2914/57

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I edited my post and my car is a 2014 Kia Optima.

Comment: @MeganMarie, check the two attached questions (one a little too much and one far too much). I suspect that your car has a little too much oil. You could siphon out the excess but I suspect you'd be fine if you leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

It is something you need to worry about. Most likely as Handy Howie points out, it could be fuel leaking through the fuel pump into the crankcase of your engine, raising the apparent amount of oil, but now it would be diluted with fuel. so far you probably have a really clean engine if this is what's happening, but as it gets worse, this could cause trouble. Best to have a qualified mechanic determine the cause of this and fix it.