# How do you remove excess engine oil?

Tags: engine

I have about 1 liter above the maximum mark on my car.  Is there an easy way(from above) to remove the oil or do I have to drain it from bottom.  I've seen someone on youtube  use a plastic syringe to take oil out, is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, we’ve talked about this issue a few times [before](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1126/57). As I said back then:

> If the oil isn't hot, almost any sort of plastic tubing can be used for siphoning. It's easiest to go in via the dip stick.
>
> Remember not to use the "suck start" siphoning method as you don't want a mouthful of oil. If you have a long enough piece of tubing, you can stick the excess down the dipstick tube, put your thumb over the end, pull out the slack (that is now full of oil) and you'll have an immediate siphon.
>
> Also remember to siphon the oil back into the original container - you might as well keep it until you do need it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally your oil-filler-cap is located on your valve cover and you do not have direct access to the oil-reservoir through that. What could work is to use the opening where your dipstick normally sits. You'd need a small enough hose to get it down there.

I would not recommend to try it though, if anything gets stuck or breaks off and you have particles in your reservoir you´ll make matters worse. Easier and safer to just use the drain plug.

Did you accidentally put in too much? Otherwise you should probably see if there is a cause for the excess oil. If your motor does not seal properly any more, oil can get diluted with gasoline or coolant.

Comment: yes it was accidental.

Comment: safest way is drain all of it and put 4qts (or whatever) back in