# Will my car be ok if I put a extra quart of oil

Tags: oil, buick, regal

I have a 1995 Buick Regal three weeks ago I put two quarts of oil in it I was checking it today and it’s too full past the full mark but I’m having no issues because of it not overheating or running bad or smoke coming out engine . But I’m still worried ..will it be ok ?

Comment: How far past the full mark is it? A little bit is usually fine.

Comment: [This Q/A should answer your question.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1125/4152) If it does, please let me know, because your question is basically a duplicate of it.